# In TFS online how to add reference to third party dll in asp.net website

Tags: tfsbuild, azure-pipelines

In TFS online, I have checked in the files of complete solution. The bin folder of website is not uploaded to TFS online. The build is giving the error like "Could not load file or assembly 'AjaxControlToolkit' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."

I wanted to know how to add the third party dll reference in VSTS.

Comment: How did you define your build definition?

Answer (score 0):

To promote a cleaner development environment and to reduce repository size, NuGet Package Restore installs all a project's dependencies as listed in either the project file or packages.config. So you need to add `Nuget restore` task before `Build` task to restore the packages:

[image]

Package restore makes sure that all a project's dependencies are available without storing those packages in source control. You need to view the website below to get more information of `Package restore`:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-restore